# Display icons along with the strings in alertdialogbox

Tags: android

Hi i am displaying the alert dialog box using below code

final CharSequence[] items = {"Email", "Phone"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

But I want to display the icons with that names.For x in above code i am taking email and phone.emailIcon comes with email name.
For this what can i do give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add a custom adapter and a custom view for the strings, look at this link for an example:

http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/10/arrayadapter-and-alertdialog-for-single-choice-items/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.